# Parsing Array in PHP based on Key Values

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, parsing

Basic php question here. The following SQL code returns an array containing a key called 'date'. All I want to do is parse the 'date' value based on the key name. Any help?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE columnName ='value'") or die(mysql_error());
 $data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
  $data[] = $row;
}
echo $data->{'date'}
```

Comment: No, what you doing is calling an object property, i mean `$data->{'date'}`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Just a suggestion you can work with NOTORM to take care of sql queries , an awesome library http://www.notorm.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here you go

With Foreach

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
   if($key == 'date')
   {
      // do you parsing stuff
   }
}
```

Without foreach

```
$parsing_date = $data['date'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using object syntax on an array which you can't do.

```
 echo $data['date'],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key == 'date')
    {
        echo "Date Value: '".$value."'";
        // Do your stuffs...
        echo "Date Final Value: '".$value."'";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_assoc returns an ASSOCiative array. Which means it returns an array with your table name fields as keys. For example if your table has 3 columns 'date', 'name', and 'color'

Then you would access those fields in the following way.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE columnName ='value'") or die(mysql_error());
 $data = array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
  echo $row['date']; //Prints the rows date field
  echo $row['name']; //Prints the row name field and so on.
}
```